# Cannot create a SELECT query in a function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, function, select

I am trying to build a function that would return the `SUM` of a value but when I type in this function, I get an error :

```
CREATE FUNCTION calculatesSummaryDiscount(@f1034 int, @f65 money, @f1032 int)
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
       SELECT SUM(@F65), MAX(@F1032) 
       FROM SAL_TTL
       WHERE 
           @F1032 = 91 
           AND @F1034 IN (8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,3340,3650))
END
```

The code itself works when not in a function so I have to figure out how to merge it in a function so I can call its value after.

Comment: That function is failing not because of the select query, but because there are two columns in the select statement that the function returns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring function as return type Money, but trying to return table. Create [Table-Valued Function](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/167399/Using-Table-Valued-Functions-in-SQL-Server) instead or remove `MAX(@F1032)` from the SELECT statement.